# Java -file not being read correctly

Tags: java

this is a post-fix expression calculator and file reader that uses file input to operate on. When F is pressed and the file name is entered the program is suppose to operate on the contents of the file and give output if valid, however it keeps jumping straight to the catch and throwing up an error. I cant see why, any suggestions?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String option;
        char letter;
    while(true)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter K to input data or F to use file input");
        option = scanner.nextLine();
        letter = option.charAt(0);

        switch (Character.toUpperCase(letter)) 
        {
        case 'K': 
        System.out.println("Please enter a calculation, or press enter to close");

        String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.equals(""))
            {
                System.out.println("Calculator has been closed");
                System.exit(0); 
            }

        String [] element = line.split(" "); 

            if (element.length == 3) 
            {
            System.out.println("You enter: " + element[0]+ " " + element[1]+" " + element[2]); 
            try{
                double number1, number2;
                number1 = Double.parseDouble(element[0]);
                number2 = Double.parseDouble(element[1]); 

                    if (element[2].equals("+"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (number1 + number2));
                    }
                    else if (element[2].equals("/"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (number1 / number2));
                    }
                    else if (element[2].equals("-"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (number1 - number2));
                    }
                    else if (element[2].equals("*"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (number1 * number2));
                    }
                    else{
                    System.out.println("That is incorect input; please try again");
                    scanner.close();
                    }
                }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
                }
        }
            else{
                System.out.println("You have inserted Incorrect input");
            }

        break;
        case 'F':
            try{
            System.out.println("you have chosen to use a file input");
            Scanner file = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("input file name:");
            String input = file.nextLine ();
            Scanner s = new Scanner (new File (input));


                while ( s.hasNext() ) {

            line = s.nextLine();
            String FileInput [] =input.split(" ");

                try
                {
                    double inp1, inp2;
                    inp1 = Double.parseDouble(FileInput[0]);
                    inp2 = Double.parseDouble(FileInput[1]);

                    if (FileInput[2].equals("+"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (inp1 + inp2));
                    }
                    else if (FileInput[2].equals("/"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (inp1 / inp2));
                    }
                    else if (FileInput[2].equals("-"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (inp1 - inp2));
                    }
                    else if (FileInput[2].equals("*"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Total:" + (inp1 * inp2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("That is incorect input; please try again");
                    }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid number" + e);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nEOF");
            file.close();
            s.close();
            break;
            }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("incorrect filename");
            }   
            default:
    System.out.println("Incorrect letter entered");
    }           
 }
}
}
```

Comment: whats the error? I see numberformat exception or filenotfound exception. which one is it? Also try changing the `s.hasNext()` to `s.hasNextLine()`

Comment: And the error it's "throwing up" is...? (Always report the actual exception being thrown.) It would also help if you reformatted your code...

Comment: Also note that most of the code you've presented seems pretty irrelevant to the problem. My guess is that the problem is *actually* that you're creating multiple scanners on System.in, but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

you should create Scanner instance only once.
Place
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`
as a first statement in your main (before the loop), and remove other `new Scanner`
The reason is that each Scanner is buffered.